# Async NodeJS request to Redis db

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to do several request to Redis db, and I need the response from a request to do the next one.

Let's analyze this example:
(I'm using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) for the requests)

```
var message-id = undefined;

// request the next id
client.incr("message-id", function(err, id) {
    message-id = id;
});

// use the 'next id' for storing a message
client.hmset("messages", message-id, messageContent);
```

This way doesn't work, because message-id id still undefined when I call `client.hmdet()`.

The following is the lazy way, and it consist in put the `client.hmdet()` inside the `client.incr()` callback.
    var message-id = undefined;

```
// request the next id
client.incr("message-id", function(err, id) {
    message-id = id;

    // use the 'next id' for storing a message
    client.hmset("messages", message-id, messageContent, function(){
        //more request here
    });
});
```

I think this is not a good way to proceed, because if I have lots chained request, I need to put each request inside its previous request callback, and this will create a block of code hard to maintain.

I'm interested in the best practices for doing lots of request asynchronously. Can someone advise me?

Comment: you'r missing a closing ) in line 6 of the first code block

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to have a look to the [async module](https://npmjs.org/package/async), it implements several patterns that you can use.
your example async waterfall

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
   // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

And also if you want to explore other possibilities beyond the callback pattern, you have the [q module](https://npmjs.org/package/q) that implements [promises A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/%E2%80%8E)

Comment: Thanks! Q module is really interesting!

Comment: Anyway, I think that could be really useful if any redis method has a flag for set the request as sync ora async... ;)

Comment: I really don't understand how to do this with promises A+ way... I't not explained well in my opinion... -_-'